# Remove extra space on tab bar - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitabbar

As you can see below, there is a thin grey bar above my tab bar on the bottom.

Is there a way to remove that completely, or make it transparent?

Thank you!

[image]

**EDIT:**

The view constraints: [image]

Comment: Can u share the screenshot of constraints you have given to that view.

Comment: @RKP In my edit, are those the constraints you're referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Set the **shadowImage** for tabBar as `[UIImage new]` and make the **backgroound** colour of tabBar as the view background colour .

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code img name replace your image

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);;
img = [img resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code only replace your image name

```
UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);;
Yourview = [Yourview resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
```

Hope this will help you great.

Comment: It is not an image, but instead a UIView. Is there a way to use your code differently?